# How to decrypt a password hash?

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, password-recovery, hashing

I have a MacBook Air running on OS X 10.9, and I need to recover a password.  I figured out the hash, which is `554bc9ec674ff1476b67a02518cd9e4a`, but I don't know how to decrypt it.  This is super important, all help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A hash is a hash is a hash. Not something you could decrypt.

Comment: As well, why would you post the hash online to a community of millions of people? Shouldn't be that important than...

Comment: your only recourse is rubber-hose cryptanalysis

Comment: The simplest solution would be to replace the hash that was generated from a password you know.  This is possible in most cases on Windows I have no idea if its possible on the version of OS X your using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What software can I use to decrypt a Mac OS X password hash?](http://superuser.com/questions/384324/what-software-can-i-use-to-decrypt-a-mac-os-x-password-hash), and/or [How to reset forgotten Administrator password on MacO X?](http://superuser.com/questions/716205/how-to-reset-forgotten-administrator-password-on-maco-x)

Comment: @Techie007, I don't think this needs reopened, but please note that the threads linked as duplicates with answers do not in fact answer the question, and the op has explicitly rejected answers based on password resets, rather than hash-cracking. the linked answers are just about password resets which may not allow access to previously encrypted data, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [Hashcat and oclHashcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcat), but if they don't work, there is almost nothing you can do.

It should NEVER be possible to do as you ask. 
Hashes are not encrypted data; Hashing is a one-way permanent translation from input to output, so it cannot be "decrypted".

Encryption relies on its passphrase to protect its ciphered form, so if a password is easily guessed, or inferred by timing or other environmental exploits, there is not necessarily anything wrong with the encryption system; it may just be being used poorly.

When someone can infer the original values for a hash however, then the hashing algorithm is broken, and everyone stops using it, because it is no longer safe for any purposes whatsoever.